# Simulate Late call using dynamic types

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm porting some vb.net code to C# and found a big issue that stopped my work completely.
Here is a small vb code that needs to be ported

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objSitesContainer
    Dim objSite
    Dim strSite1RDN As String = "TestSite1-MKFPKFMSJJCWJUB"
    Dim strSitesContainer As String = "LDAP://DC9.domain9.local/CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain9,DC=local"

    Try
        Const ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND = 3
        objSitesContainer = GetObject(strSitesContainer)
        objSite = objSitesContainer.Create("site", "CN=" & strSite1RDN)
        objSite.SetInfo()

         MessageBox.Show("All ok")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I used SharpDevelop to help me convert this to C# (any other online tool generates basically the same code)
The output code looks like this

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strSitesContainer = "LDAP://DC9.domain9.local/CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain9,DC=local";
        string strSite1RDN = "TestSite1-MKFPKFMSJJCWJUB";


        dynamic objSitesContainer;
        dynamic objSite;
        objSitesContainer = Interaction.GetObject(strSitesContainer);
        objSite = objSitesContainer.Create("site", "CN=" + strSite1RDN);
        objSite.SetInfo();
        MessageBox.Show("All ok");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

it compiles fine. But, it miserably fails at the run-time when calling the method "Create" with such an exception `The method or operation is not implemented`. 
Why so? isn't dynamic supposed to work same way as in VB?

Well, anyhow, I checked the reflector to see what is being generated from the VB code, here it is

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "TestSite1-MKFPKFMSJJCWJUB";
    string pathName = "LDAP://DC9.domain9.local/CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain9,DC=local";
    try
    {
        NewLateBinding.LateCall(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(NewLateBinding.LateGet(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(Interaction.GetObject(pathName, null)), null, "Create", new object[] { "site", "CN=" + str }, null, null, null)), null, "SetInfo", new object[0], null, null, null, true);
        MessageBox.Show("All ok");
    }
    catch (Exception exception1)
    {
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
        Exception exception = exception1;
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
    }
}
```

That's completely different from what anyone would expect? Why SharpDevelop generated such buggy code?

What are the best way to fix this?
There is like 1000 places where such calls exists in the application I'm porting, to do it by hand would be pretty hard I'd say.

Any ideas are welcome.
Thx

Comment: Have you verified that `objSitesContainer` is what you expect? Furthermore, is the method really implemented? Auto-generated methods throw a `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: why shall it be different? Same code in VB works as needed including the method. Testing both apps on same server, VB works, C# with dynamic crash.

Comment: I don't know how much of your code you are porting. I assumed that you might have changed `Interaction.GetObject()`, too.

Comment: just made a grep on the code, is 470 entries where such technique is used. `Interaction.GetObject()` is a .NET method, not my.

Comment: @NicoSchertler original question is still valid, have you verified that the instance you get back from `Interaction.GetObject()` is the instance you expect?